# Comparing the kernel's net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range setting to a webserver's port setting

Tags: nginx, port, kernel, socket

Being new to webservers, I need to clarify a concept. Apologies if this is a less-than-stellar question.

It's [recommended](https://tweaked.io/guide/kernel/) to set `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535` in sysctl.conf.

However, for a specific web application, nginx is programmed to listen at port `80` and `443` (for example). Then in such a scenario, why does setting the port range between 1024 to 65535 matter?

Comment: Take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` value is used to set the port range for *outgoing* connections. You generally only have to make changes to this on busy systems. Port 80 and port 443 are where webservers generally *listen*.